# Please Choose to register or to checkout as guest

Tags: magento-1.8, error, onepage-checkout, javascript, jquery

Everything was working fine on one page checkout, But now it seems to give me a error of *Please Choose to register or to checkout as guest* even if I select any of these option and try to click on Continue button.

In My Console I have these errors

```
http://domain.com/skin/frontend/base/default/css/print.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
domain.com/:100 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ready is not a function
VM111 prototype.js:1931Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
VM111 prototype.js:5734Uncaught TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is not a function
```

Please help me.

Comment: Try to disable javascript compression and flush the cache and tell me if this fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with jquery. You have included a script in your template but in a wrong way: change

$(document).ready(...

with

jQuery(document).ready...

and be sure that you included jQuery.js in your .

Comment: But it was working before and no change in code has been made since

Answer (score 0):

`$(...).ready` is a jQuery function. Since by default magento come preinstall with prototype js framework which also uses the `$` you will need to update your code to run jquery in noconflict mode.

Assuming that jQuery library is included correctly

```
jQuery(document).ready(
```

See [How to add jQuery in Magento?](http://www.magesolution.com/blog/how-to-add-jquery-in-magento/)

Comment: But it was working before and no change in code has been made since.